# What pattern am I missing

Tags: c#, .net, oop, design-patterns

I have the following interface

```
interface IConsoleHistory
{
    void Add(string entry);

    HistoryEntry GetNextEntry();

    HistoryEntry GetPreviousEntry();

    void ResetHistoryMarker();

    void Delete(HistoryEntry entry);

    void DeleteEntireHistory();
}

public class HistoryEntry
{
    public HistoryEntry(string value, int index, bool isCommand)
    {
        Value = value;
        Index = index;
        IsCommand = isCommand;
    }

    public string Value { get; private set; }

    public int Index { get; private set; }

    public bool IsCommand { get; private set; }
}
```

Based on that, I implemented an InMemoryHistory:

```
public class InMemoryHistory : IConsoleHistory
{
    protected List<string> History { get; private set; }
    private int _currentIndex;

    public InMemoryHistory() :this(new List<string>())
    {
    }

    protected InMemoryHistory(List<string> history)
    {
        History = history;
        _currentIndex = -1;
    }

    public virtual void Add(string entry)
    {
        History.Insert(0, entry);
    }

    public HistoryEntry GetNextEntry()
    {
        if (GetHighestIndex() > _currentIndex)
        {
            _currentIndex++;
            return ReturnAtIndex(_currentIndex);
        }

        return null;
    }

    private int GetHighestIndex()
    {
        return History.Count - 1;
    }

    private int GetLowestIndex()
    {
        return History.Count > 0 ? 0 : -1;
    }

    public HistoryEntry GetPreviousEntry()
    {
        if (_currentIndex > GetLowestIndex())
        {
            _currentIndex--;
            return ReturnAtIndex(_currentIndex);
        }
        _currentIndex = -1;
        return null;
    }

    private HistoryEntry ReturnAtIndex(int index)
    {
        return new HistoryEntry(History[index], index, false);
    }

    public void ResetHistoryMarker()
    {
        _currentIndex = -1;
    }

    public void Delete(HistoryEntry entry)
    {
        if (History.ElementAtOrDefault(entry.Index) != null)
        {
            History.RemoveAt(entry.Index);
        }
    }

    public void DeleteEntireHistory()
    {
        History.Clear();
    }
}
```

Now I wanted to have a file based history. To keep the code DRY I wanted to inherit from the InMemoryHistory and just persist the whole List after every addition.

```
public class FileBasedHistory : InMemoryHistory
{
    private readonly string _fileName;

    public FileBasedHistory():this("history.txt")
    {
    }

    public FileBasedHistory(string fileName) :base(GetHistoryFromFile(fileName))
    {
        _fileName = fileName;
    }

    public override void Add(string entry)
    {
        base.Add(entry);
        WriteToDisk();
    }

    private void WriteToDisk()
    {
        using(var textWriter = new StreamWriter(_fileName, false, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            History.ForEach(textWriter.WriteLine);
        }
    }

    private static List<string> GetHistoryFromFile(string fileName)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(fileName))
            return new List<string>();

        return File
            .ReadAllLines(fileName)
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

That works like a charme. What bothers me though is that I need the static `GetHistoryFromFile` method. It's not really a big deal but I wonder if I'm missing a pattern that would be more appropriate for this situation?

**UPDATE**

As Keith already suggested. It's also the inheritance approach that kinda bothers me. Inheritance should always be a question of *is a*.

You can not say: *"A FileBasedHistory **is a** InMemoryHistory"*

So I wonder if I should try to use the *StrategyPattern* for this. Or maybe write an AbstractConsole that implements parts of the logic but leaves room for extensions. Any suggestion on how to refactor it?

Answer (score 2):

I find it odd you are passing in a list as a constructor.   You don't have to do it that way at all...

rather than thinking of your GetHistoryFromFile as creating a new list, think of it as a method to load into an existing list  ( it becomes more generally useful that way also... as it could load multiple files into a history ).

Also removing and clearing don't work properly for writing to disk...

Also writing a line by line to disk is likely to get quite slow...

Also, your InMemory and File based storage may be suffering from Coincidental coupling.  Meaning while they are similarish at the moment, there's a likely chance for them to diverge.  eg,  if your disk based system used rolling history files and cached history.  So don't get too attached to the InMemory and File to remain in a inheritance structure, it may be easier to break them apart

Comment: I like your thinking. Especially about that last part. I don't like the inheritance approach neither. But I also want to share as much code as possible without too tight coupeling. I tweaked my initial question a little bit. Do you mind sharing some code how you would rewrite it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got it just perfect. `GetHistoryFromFile` only applies to a `FileBasedHistory`, so it makes sense that it should be there.

Comment: It's the staticness that kinda bothers me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Iterator` here. These three methods used only for iterating over your data:

```
HistoryEntry GetNextEntry();
HistoryEntry GetPreviousEntry();
void ResetHistoryMarker();
```

And these methods are for managing data:

```
void Add(string entry);
void Delete(HistoryEntry entry);
void DeleteEntireHistory();
```

I think this is a different responsibilities, and I'd moved them to different classes.

Comment: I was thinking about implementing `IEnumerable<string>` or `ICollection<string>` but several things kept me away from it. First, I like the explicitness of my custom interface. I also wanted to have the GetNextEntry/GetPreviousEntry methods to directly return the value. And last but not least, the history has to support forward and backward iteration.

However, that's actually unrelated to what really bothers me about the code. I'm going to add some more thoughts about my concerns to my initial question.

Comment: Implementing `IEnumerable` is not same as creating iterator class. `IEnumerator` is default iterator interface in .net, but I'm talking about custom iterator.